# My index page does not link to the stylesheets folder located in public / stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following view

```
app/views/people/index.html.erb
```

and layout `app /views/layout/application.html.erb`

Content of `application.html.erb`

```
<link href="/assets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I go to `localserver:3000/people`

The styles of the `public / stylesheets` folder are not applied

The source code localserver:3000/people

```
<link href="/assets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Post your `index.html.erb` file.

Comment: Did that worked for you?

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <h1>People</h1>

<ul>
<% @people.each do |person| %>
    <li><%= link_to person, person_path(person) %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to your `index.html.erb` should do the trick

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "all" %>
```

For more details,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag)**

Comment: Give this line `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "all" %>` instead of this one `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>`.

Comment: Should link to 

<link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1381421296" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 


But links to 

<link href="/assets/cache.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Bacause assets folder?

Comment: Remove that line and give `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`

Comment: When rails starts  (rails s) appears Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.

Comment: @user3554170 What? I didn't get that.

Comment: @user3554170 try restarting the server and check again